# Apache: Redirect site visitors from sub-directory to subdomain and preserve trailing URL after sub-directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Running LAMP stack...

I'm attempting to redirect my company's domain.com/blog traffic to a new sub-domain (e.g. blog.domain.com) while preserving any trailing URL after the sub-directory (domain.com/blog/article1234 turns into blog.domain.com/article1234).

I've attempted several variations with my .htaccess file using rewrite rules and conditions and this seems to be the closest I've gotten to success:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ https://blog.domain.com/ [NC,R,L]
```

I also thought I was getting close with this:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog.domain.com/?p=$1 [R=302,L]
```

But that ended up breaking URLs somehow. I don't personally care if it's 302 or 301 - we intend to keep this sub-domain indefinitely but I've had nightmarish issues with 301s in the past. Open to anything at this point.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt was close to perfect, I just made some small modifications:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?blog/?(.*)$ blog.domain.com/$1 [R=302,END,QSA]
```

In case you use an older apache server you may have to replace the `END` flag with the `L` flag which usually works unless you have conflicting rules.

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).